# How to pick up where you left off in an Access form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a table and form that allows our company's processors track volumes of incoming items that they process each day. For example, some of my fields are: ServicerName,  DateOfEntry, PhoneCallsCompleted, ChecksCompleted, and EmailsCompleted. Each row in the table indicates how many items in various categories that a processor processed in a specific day. If the users closes out of the form and comes back to it later in the day, I want it to pick up on the record where they left off. My attempt to solve this was by creating a calculated field called ServicerNamePlusDateOfEntry that concatenates the values in the ServicerName and DateOfEntry fields. The following code will take the user back to an existing entry if there is already an entry for a specific date and processor name. However, it also creates an additional empty record.

```
Private Sub ServicerName_AfterUpdate()
    Dim RepName As String
    Dim EnteredDate As Date
    Dim NamePlusDate As String
    RepName = ServicerName.Value
    EnteredDate = DateOfEntry.Value
    NamePlusDate = RepName & " " & EnteredDate

    DoCmd.FindRecord NamePlusDate, acAnywhere, True, acSearchAll, True, 
    acAll, True

End Sub
```

I need to figure out how to get it to not create an additional record.

Comment: Delvin, could you provide in your question  the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Comment: Are there several users who share that DB, each one with his own 'last record' ?

Comment: What is the PK of the underlying dataset ?

Comment: The primary key is an autonumber field called ID. And yes, there would be several users accessing this form.

Comment: Basically, I want the user to start the day by selecting today's date for the DateOfEntry field and their name for the ServicerName field and then start entering their totals as they process items. If they close out and come back later in the day, and there is already an existing record that has today's date and their name in the ServicerName field, I want the form to redirect them to that existing record.

Comment: Maybe this could work. If every worker has its own `ServicerName` you could filter  the results by active `ServicerName` and sort the records from Z to A using your primary key autonumber field. That way, the first record should be always the last entered by that user with that specific `ServicerName`. Welcome to SO

Answer (score 0):

If the fields ServicerName and DateOfEntry are unbound and are the first controls on the form so that nothing else has been entered yet, then I think the procedure could navigate to a matching record if it exists once they have been filled in without creating a new record, or, if no matching record was found, save the two text entries to the underlying recordset along with the rest of the form when it is saved.